# Impossible to connect to wifi

Tags: 12.04, wireless

Following my question from yesterday where I couldn't find one particular wifi, this wifi does now appear correctly. But I can't connect to it. I have the right password (it is in my phone, and I use it), but when I click on the network and enter the password, it tries for a moment and then prompts me the password window again, without connecting.

I'm on Ubuntu 12.04 with a HP Mini 5103, with Intel.

Thanks !

Comment: Hit the wireless icon on the top right > Edit Connections... > delete the WiFi you're trying to connect to. Then, in a terminal (Ctrl+Alt+T), type `sudo restart network-manager` (enter your password when asked). Try to connect to the WiFi again, and make sure you're typing the correct password (make use of the "Show password" checkbox to see what you typed).

Comment: I tried, thanks, but it didn't work... I really don't understand. Is it normal that in the wifi list (when I click on the wireless icon), this wireless network (that has the most strength & is closest) isn't in the 5 first ones? I have to go to "more networks". Well anyway this didn't work, still the same problem. Broadcom BCM43224 btw.

Comment: No, I guess it's okay for the closest wireless to be in the "more networks" list, it's just how it's designed. Anyways, I see that you got it fixed, although we don't know the cause of the problem =). Don't forget to mark your answer as accepted when you can.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to get it wired via ethernet finally.

Then I simply upgraded to 12.10.

I got connected to the wifi but internet didn't work. I just couldn't connect to any webpage.

But, miracle:

sudo dhclient wlan0

And IT ALL WORKED.
Cheers

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried reinstalling the driver?

```
sudo apt-get install linux-headers-generic
sudo apt-get install linux-headers-$(uname -r)
sudo apt-get install --reinstall bcmwl-kernel-source
sudo modprobe wl
```

More info about Broadcom WiFi drivers here: [Installing Broadcom Wireless Drivers](https://askubuntu.com/questions/55868/how-to-install-a-broadcom-wireless-driver)